# Trying to replace all files in a directory and subdirectories with a source file without altering their name

Tags: batch-file

let's say I have c:\test
and "test" has 100 png images that I want to replace with my own png image, but I don't want to change the name of the images in \test\ .

How would I do that with a batch file? I tried messing around with some FOR cycles but I'm not really experienced with them.

This is the code that I made, it will probably make you cry, but I'm quite a beginner so please forgive me.

```
@echo off
for /r %%f in (*) do (
set /a nmb=%random%
set /a name=%%~nxf
copy source.png D:\tobereplaced
rename D:\tobereplaced\%name% %nmb%
pause>nul
)
```

line 2: for every file in the directory and subdirectories take the file name and do:
line3: assign to nmb a random number

line4: assign to name the file name --->Problem: if I try to do echo %name% all I get is "ECHO DISABLED" which means that what I'm trying to assign to "name" is wrong.

line5: copy the source to the folder where I want to replace the files.

line6: rename the source.png file to whatever name the original file had.

Comment: You don't need the rename command. You can change the file name with the copy command by specifying the new file name with the destination path. It physically says you can do that in the help file for the COPY command.

Comment: Aight thanks, found my way around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution

```
@echo off
for /r %%f in (*) do (
echo %%f
copy sorgente.png %%f
pause>nul
)
```

First i set my source files to read only because it would replace them too.